# Can I trigger xmodmap on USB keyboard connection, as a user?

Tags: udev, usb-device, xmodmap, hid

I remap my <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> to <kbd>Compose</kbd> with `xmodmap` in my `.profile`. But when I disconnect my USB keyboard and reconnect it I have to rerun `xmodmap` for it to take effect again.

Is there a way, I suspect as a udev rule for hids, for me to automate this, as a user that has no rights to edit `/etc`?

The docs only mention `/etc/udev/rules.d` but no `~/.config` or `~/.local` or any hooks I can use as a user.

Comment: Not with udev rules. You can do that from any X11 app (no root needed), by monitoring xinput events. There's a program which can interface xinput events to shell scripts (`inputplug`), but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: @UncleBilly thanks I'll look into it.